# How can I track place where file has been uploaded to the server?

Tags: django, django-file-upload

Tell me please, can I determine when loading files from a directory it was loaded?

`InMemoryUploadedFile` contains only the file name. I.e. simply `Foto.jpg`.

I would like to see there for example: `c:\windows\blablabla\Foto.jpg`.

Or is it impossible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be it possible via JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this is not possible.
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html